# How to find all the available MIDI ports over network using CoreMIDI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, coremidi

I am working on an app which needs to send Midi over wifi. I looked at CoreMIDI and the MIDINetworkSession class. I have set the default session's policy to .anyone and also enabled it. But I am not clear what to do next. I looked at PGMidi but it didn't list out the remote host's MIDI ports after making changes to the session.

What I want is a list of all the MIDI ports that I can connect to on the remote machine running MacOSX.

Is it even possible? Can someone please give me some hints?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. Here is what I did:

**Scanning the remote service**
Suppose my mac is running a MIDI session which is advertised over Bonjour. I used NetServiceBrowser to scan the local network and find out which server supports "_apple-midi._udp" service. [Look at the documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/netservicebrowser). NetServiceBrowserDelegate receives a service in the delegate callbacks. Please note that the service object is not yet resolved against the DNS and therefore doesn't contain IP address of the host. 
The next step is to resolve the service by using a NetServiceDelegate. The service object passed in the success delegate callback contains everything that is there to know about that service. So now, you have a list of IP addresses/hostnames and corresponding port numbers.

**Sending MIDI**
Create a MIDINetworkConnection instance using the ip address/hostname and the port number. It looks like a synchronous call, so may be it doesn't contact the server itself. Next, get all the midi devices and iterate over Entities and Destinations. [Its given in this document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremidi/midi_services)